# jQuery scroll on Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, scroll, mobile-safari

I'm developing and website and I need it to scroll to an anchor. It needs to be animated, so I decided to use jQuery for that. I tried this:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

It works perfectly on the desktop. On Mobile Safari it first goes to the top of the page, then it scrolls to the anchor I want it to scroll to. What's the trick to make it work on Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var top = $("#"+id).offset().top; //anchor top offset from doc top
$(window).scrollTop(top);
```